# the range of 'the rolls' in 'Please pass the rolls'

Tags: definite-article, semantics

**Situation:** You see several rolls on the table in front of you.
You hear, "Please pass the rolls."
Could you possibly pass just one roll? In other words, does 'the rolls' mean to range from all the rolls there to just one roll from there?
This is purely a semantic question, not a pragmatic one, with etiquette, protocols, hygiene, consideration for the speaker aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to untangle the pragmatic from the semantic. And the key to understanding this is "The".

"The rolls" is plural, so the speaker is referring to more than one.  It uses a definite article, so the speaker believes that, in context, the answer to the question "which rolls" is understood by the listener.

And this is why you can't ignore the pragmatic.  The word "the" requires a pragmatic understanding.  The speaker uses "the" because there is a group of rolls that is clearly identifiable to the listener that can be passed.  Probably it is something like "the rolls in the basket of rolls on the table"

If there is a group of rolls on the table, "the rolls" would refer to that whole group... but here is where the pragmatic comes in again since "the rolls" is more likely to refer to an easily passed basket, which the speaker mistaken believes exists.

So pragmatically, you could pass one roll. But from a "purely semantic" analysis, "the rolls" means "the whole collection of rolls, the identity of which you know". And you should pass all of them.

Comment: Thanks James. Yes, semantically it refers to the whole set of rolls that the speaker think the hearer can uniquely identify (ref. Russellian difinition). So if there are no baskets, if the rolls were somehow placed, say, on a large plate, pragmatically you would pick one (or any number of rolls you think fit) and give it (them) to the speaker. Right?

Comment: Pragmatically you could pass the plate, or one roll, or you could ask "how many?"  Or pass one roll while asking "do you want any more?"  or...